# Sharepoint designer does not correctly display page

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I open mysite page in sharepoint designer the page (see [fullscreen picture)](http://img246.imageshack.us/img246/2805/sharepointdesignerprobl.png) is not displayed correctly. I`m willing to edit and create new theme using this mysite.
However when I open sharepoint server homepage (https://myserver/Pages/Default.aspx) in designer, everything is ok.

Thank You all for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint designer adds some borders, columns, and other crap to the render, so you shouldn't rely on it. It's page rendering can only guide you, it doesn't do the exact design.

Comment: The extra borders are no problem, just the contents are misplaced.